# escape $0, $1, .. with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have something similar to this:

```
<?php
$text = 'lorem ipsum';
$pattern = '/lorem/';
$value = 'test $0';

$text = preg_replace($pattern, $value, $text);
?>
```

I want the final value of $text to be 'test $0 ipsum'. Problem is $0 is interpreted as a variable and replaced with 'lorem', so I get 'test lorem ipsum'.

Is there a way to disable this feature of preg_replace() ?

The example above is of course simplified. What I'm actually doing is making a templating script where I replace placeholders with file contents, which can be javascript, html, etc... So it would be great to act on the preg_replace function itself rather than being forced to modify all the files making sure they have escaping characters.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `preg_replace` with an escape for any back reference in replacement value:

```
<?php
$text = 'lorem ipsum';
$pattern = '/lorem/';
$value = 'test $0';
echo preg_replace($pattern, preg_replace('/\$(\d+)/', '\\\$$1', $value), $text);
```

`\$(\d+)` searches for any `$` and then one or more numbers
`\\\$$1`  replaces the `$` with `\$` because the first `\\` escapes the backslash to be literal for the PHP. `$1` is the first capture group which is the number(s).

https://3v4l.org/J8aps

Comment: I will go with that solution. Thank you very much for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

Use [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), it's the right tool for that manipulation:

```
$text = 'lorem ipsum';
$pattern = '/lorem/';
$value = 'test $0';
$text = preg_replace($pattern, preg_quote($value), $text);
echo $text;
```

**Output:**

```
test $0 ipsum
```